# My DOM element already has some divs. Can I use D3 to add more?

Tags: html, d3.js

Let's say I have a document which looks like this:

```html
<body>
  <div>1st div</div>
  <div>2nd div</div>
  <div>3rd div</div>
</body>
```

and I want to turn it into this:

```html
<body>
  <div>1st div</div>
  <div>2nd div</div>
  <div>3rd div</div>
  <div>4th div - bound to data</div>
  <div>5th div - bound to data</div>
  <div>6th div - bound to data</div>
</body>
```

Can I do this with D3?  I know how to add three divs bound to data to an empty DOM element, but everything I've tried on a nonempty DOM element messes with existing divs or simply doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have to use `d3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want the first three divs bound to data at all - say you just have a 3 element array - I would recommend you add a class to the bound divs, so they can be distinguished from the others.

```js
d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('div.bound')
  .data(d3.range(4, 7))
  .enter()
  .append('div').classed('bound', true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d + 'th div - bound to data';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>1st div</div>
  <div>2nd div</div>
  <div>3rd div</div>
</body>
```

So your output becomes:

```
<body>
  <div>1st div</div>
  <div>2nd div</div>
  <div>3rd div</div>
  <div class="bound">4th div - bound to data</div>
  <div class="bound">5th div - bound to data</div>
  <div class="bound">6th div - bound to data</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by specifying a key function when calling [`selection.data([values[, key]])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

```js
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(d3.range(4,7), function(d) { return d; })  // use a key function
  .enter().append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d + "th div"; });

// Code below just for demonstration purposes showing the data bound to each div
d3.selectAll("div")
  .text(function(d,i) {
    return d3.select(this).text() + " -- index: " + i + " data bound: " + d;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>1st div</div>
<div>2nd div</div>
<div>3rd div</div>
```

By using the key function all newly bound data will end up in the enter selection whereby appending new `<div>`s with data bound to just them. All existing  `<div>`s will be put in the exit selection which, at least for your purposes, might simply be ignored.

Comment: The key function is identity by default - your answer suffers from the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/36053231/249933 in that all divs are databound.

Comment: @ColinE That is not correct, there is no default key function, unless you explicitly define one. If no key function is specified at all, the data will be joined by index, which will yield different results. My snippet behaves exactly as requested, it binds data to only the newly appended divs. Please see the updated version which prints the div's index and the data bound right next to it.

Answer (score -1):

That is exactly what d3 is made for.

```js
d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(d3.range(6))
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .text(function(_, i) {
    return (i + 1) + 'th div - bound to data';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>1st div</div>
  <div>2nd div</div>
  <div>3rd div</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This will also bind data to existing divs 1-3, though, which is not what OP asked for.